# What does <<= operator mean in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, bit-manipulation, bit

Can you please explain this code snippet from [HashMap constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap) specifically the line

> capacity <<= 1:

```
// Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
198         int capacity = 1;
199         while (capacity < initialCapacity)
200             capacity <<= 1;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is equivalent to `capacity = capacity << 1;`.
That operation shifts capacity's bits one position to the left, which is equivalent to multiplying by 2.

The specific code you posted finds the smallest power of 2 which is larger than `initialCapacity`.

So if `initialCapacity` is 27, for example, `capacity` will be 32 (2^5) after the loop.

Comment: Not strictly equivalent, though. Different precedence rules may apply.

Comment: @assylias but why a power of 2 ? if we take division method for hashing and we take mod of a power of 2(say 2^w) , we don't even consider right most  w bits I think ...

Comment: @Geek You would be right except HashMap also uses a rehashing method called `hash(int)` which computes `h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);` ;)

Comment: @StephenC HashMap always uses a power of 2 for its capacity.

Comment: @StephenC what do you mean by "the "power of 2" bit is AN EXAMPLE." . It seems from the code that HashMap ALWAYS will have a power of 2 as its capacity irrespective of is load factor .

Comment: @PeterLawrey whats going on in that fancy mehthod ? I am poor in bit manipulation ....

Comment: @Geek the method finds the smallest power of 2 that is larger than initialCapacity. So if initialCapacity = 27 for example, capacity will be 32 (2^5) after that loop.

Comment: @assylias I see now what it is doing , but again why are they going for this power of 2 approach which seems counter intuitive to me ...How this double hashing is solving the problem of taking all bits into consideration .

Comment: @Geek Simply put, the hash method pull down bits from the 20th and 12th and then the 7th and 4th for a combined effect of taking bits from the 4, 7, 12, 16, 19, 20, 24 and 27th bits. i.e. jumbles them all up. In the case of the default size, 16, the top bit is ignored, but for a size of 32+ all the bits are used.

Comment: @Geek The logic is that doing a rehash and a bit mask and is faster than using `%` and handling the sign (which involves a branch)

Comment: @PeterLawrey thanks for this explanation . I see now the intuition for going for 2^w approach .

Comment: @Geek I suspect avoiding the branch prediction misses is the main gain. ;)

Comment: @Peter, the branch is easily removed by `hash&Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  mod is just an expensive operation (like 30 times more expensive than bitwise AND and uses an extra CPU register -- also taxing). The latter - bitwise and Integer.MAX_VALUE shall always be applied for hash index into an array with the top bit reserved for 'state'. I know of no hashtable in java that uses 32 bits of the provided `hashCode()`

Comment: @Geek, the main reason is that mod is quite expensive compared to bitwise and.

Comment: @Peter, Using mod is justified with prime number sized table since it reduces collisions. Collision reduction is improved by the very bit scramble you explain. Collisions in java.util.HashMap are sorta expensive since they lead to a cache-miss... open address table is usually better with pow2 sized table and collisions are cheaper. Overall like I have stated multiple times java.util.HashMap blows hard

Answer (score 4):

Just like `var += 1` is about equivalent to `var = var + 1`, what you see here (`var <<= 1`) is about equivalent to `var = var << 1`, which is "set `var` to be the result of a `1`-position binary left-shift of `var`."

In this very specific case, it's actually a slightly (runtime) faster way of expressing `capacity *= 2` (because a bitwise left-shift of 1 position is equivalent to a multiplication by 2).

Answer (score 3):

It is equivalent of

```
capacity = capacity << 1;
```

which shifts bits in `capacity` one position to the left (so i.e. `00011011` becomes `00110110`).

Answer (score 0):

every time this comes out of the loop the value of 'capacity' goes  2 raised by a  power higher.

like initially it is 1 i.e.2^0; the operation(capacity <<= 1) for the first time makes it 2^1 and then 2^2 and so on.
May be you would like to see the more on it at  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm