# Bitshift and equals together

Tags: c

What does >>= do in this example?

```
byte fsr = 2;
fsr >>= 2;
```

I came across it here:
https://github.com/sparkfun/MMA8452_Accelerometer/blob/master/Firmware/MMA8452Q_BasicExample/MMA8452Q_BasicExample.ino

Comment: Same concept as `+=`.

Comment: StackOverflow has a better search engine than Google, so you can search for the token directly (in quotes): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3E%3E=%22

Comment: You may also use your common sense (if any) to search for a [slightly broader category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does <<= operator mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071826/what-does-operator-mean-in-java)

Answer (score 11):

It does this:

```
fsr = fsr >> 2;
```

Comment: (However it will evaluate `fsr` only once, in cases where `fsr` is an expression that has side-effects on evaluation. In other cases it is 100% equivalent)

Comment: @Patashu, you mean like `*getPtr() >>= 2;` where `getPtr` has a side-effect?

Comment: @gxzm0 Yes, think about what the equivalent code without `>>=` is.

Comment: @Patashu `byte* ptr = getPtr(); *ptr = *ptr >> 2;`

Comment: @gxzm0 I was thinking more like `*getPtr() = *getPtr() >> 2`

Comment: This is called an *in-place shift operator*.

Answer (score 2):

```
fsr >>= 2;
```

is

```
fsr = fsr >> 2;
```

In Bitwise Context, two bit places to the right is being shifted.

In Arithmetic context, the number in fsr is being divided by 2^2(4);